# Curl command with jq

Tags: curl, jq

learning the curl command first time, I am using this jason

```
{
  "count": 32,
  "results": [
    {
      "@class": "SFTPServer",
      "enabled": true,
      "businessProtocol": "Raw",
      "friendlyName": "AP.CD.CLEANCLAIMS.KP.EPIC",
      "backupMessages": true,
      "maxConcurrentConnections": 100,
      "inlineProcessors": "/v1/application/exchange/190571504/inlineProcessors",
      "inlinePostProcessors": "/v1/application/exchange/190571504/inlinePostProcessors",
      "schedule": "/v1/application/exchange/190571504/schedules",
      "metadataFixedItems": {},
      "restrictConsumableFileSize": false,
      "maxConsumableFileSize": 0,
      "metatadaTemplate": {
        "defaultMetadataTemplate": "",
        "enabledByProtocol": false,
        "metadataTemplatePolicy": "NEVER",
        "priorityOverFixedAttributes": false
      },
      "addressingRules": "/v1/application/exchange/pickup/190571504/addressing",
      "useCommunityMessageDelivery": true,
      "shouldOverrideDirection": false,
      "overrideDirection": null,
      "useContentProcessing": false,
      "ediSplitterEnabled": false,
      "serviceId": null,
      "service": null,
      "pickupGroupStatus": null,
      "pickupGroup": null,
      "remoteUrl": "sftp://kpepicusr@mft-b2bi-qa.pldc.kp.org:5025/upload",
      "serverSettings": "/v1/embedded/server/115530501",
      "localPort": 5025,
      "defaultUser": null,
      "alwaysConsumeFromSubdirs": true,
      "modifySftpServerDirectory": true,
      "sequenced": false,
      "sequenceTimeoutSeconds": 60,
      "url": "sftp://kpepicusr@mft-b2bi-qa.pldc.kp.org:5025/upload",
      "subDirectories": "/v1/application/exchange/190571504/sftpSubDirectory",
      "encryptBackup": false,
      "@id": "190571504"
    },
```

this command is working:

```
curl -k -sS -X GET -u "1:2" "http://csc2cxn00001736.cnge/pickup?offset=0&orderBy=name" -H "accept: application/json" | jq '.results'
```

This one, however, gives a syntax error:

```
$ curl -k -sS -X GET -u "1:2" "http://csc2cxn00001736.cloud.kp.org:6080/api/v1/application/exchange/pickup?offset=0&orderBy=name" -H "accept: application/json" | jq '.results.friendlyName'
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "friendlyName" SND_B2Bi0[axway@csc2cxn00001722
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the actual error. We can't help debug an error if you don't tell us what that error is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show us the `json` you get by using `curl`

Comment: I updated my question with the jason. and this is the error I am receiving:                                             SND_B2Bi0[axway@csc2cxn00001722 ~]$ curl -k -sS -X GET -u "admin:Secret2cQA" "http://csc2cxn00001736.cloud.kp.org:608nge/pickup?offset=0&orderBy=name" -H "accept: application/json" | jq '.results.friendlyName'
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "friendlyName"
SND_B2Bi0[axway@csc2cxn00001722 ~]$

Comment: `.results` is an array, not an object. Do you want the `friendlyName` of the first element of the array? Of all the elements?

Comment: of all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to address all elements of the array like:

```
jq '.results[].friendlyName'
```

Comment: thank you it worked. it returned all the friendly names. now trying to return @id values.  it  gave this error

Comment: SND_B2Bi0[axway@csc2cxn00001722 ~]$ curl -k -sS -X GET -u "admin:Secret2cQA" "http://csc2cxn00001736.cloud.kp.org:608nge/pickup?offset=0&orderBy=name" -H "accept: application/json" | jq '.results[].@id'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.results[].@id           
jq: 1 compile error
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 12800)

Comment: @Chandana put the `@id` in quotes: `jq '.results[]."@id"'`

Comment: @Chandana When asking questions here, make sure to tell us what it is you want to do, not just what you are having issues with. If all you want to do is to parse out individual fields from this JSON data, then fine. If you want to filter the data by the fields, sort it and/or make some kind of final report of aggregated data, then let us know and we would be able to give you more helpful answers rather than solutions to issues that don't actually take you to where you want to go in the end.

Comment: Thank you @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu. it worked.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda. I will try to add more details.

Comment: @Chandana Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.